# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect when uploading file with its name

Tags: android, spring, rest, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file to Spring MVC from android, and I keep getting the HTTP 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect error.What i observed is that when i send only the file its getting uploaded and no error  but when i associate the file name with the file then i am getting this error.Below is my code.

```
        RestTemplate newRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    formHttpMessageConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF8"));
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> msgConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    msgConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
    msgConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    msgConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    newRestTemplate.setMessageConverters(msgConverters);
    newRestTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
        protected boolean hasError(HttpStatus statusCode) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    File image = new File(imagePath, upFile.getFileName());
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "bearer " + accessToken);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    map.add("file", new FileSystemResource(image));
    map.add("name", "filename");
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> imageEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> restRes = newRestTemplate.exchange(MainActivity.strUrl +"/uploadFile", HttpMethod.POST, imageEntity, String.class);
```

Above is the android code.Now the spring section are as below.

servelet.xml :

```
        <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myproject" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.example.myproject.controller.MyController"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven> 

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
     <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" />
    </bean>  

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.example.myproject</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

controller :

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile srcFile,@PathVariable("name") String filename){
        try{
            byte[] bytes = srcFile.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/ejacob/Templates/"+filename)));
            bos.write(bytes);
            bos.close();
            return "Success";
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you dont send a file name then how would the controller code look like?

Comment: If you do not send a file name then the only thing you do is removing map.add("name", "filename"); ?

Comment: @greenapps if i remove map.add("name", "filename");  from android and filename pathvariable from spring then my code will work,but if i associated that then getting error

Comment: `@PathVariable("name")` Try with `@RequestParam("name")`.

Comment: I found the solution for that by using srcFile.getOriginalFilename() in server to get the name.No need for sending name as path variable or request param.